# Media Url in TwiML request message

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have configured a url to receive TwiML message.
I receive following fields

1. Account Sid
   2.Body
   3.From
   4.MessageSid
   5.NumMedia

However, I dont receive the following

1. MediaContentType
2. MediaUrl

Though the field NumMedia has value 2, I dont receive MediaUrl.

I use c#.

Following is my class structure which will hold the request message received from Twilio

```
public class TwilioRequest
    {
        public string MessageSid { get; set; }
        public string AccountSid { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int NumMedia { get; set; }
        public List<string> MediaContentType { get; set; }
        public List<string> MediaUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: There is SmsRequest https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet/issues/125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the MMS message is received and contains media (images, videos) it will indeed put the count into the `NumMedia` field of the POST request directed at your server. The individual media urls and identifier will be appended their consecutive sequence numbers (up to 10) and that would result in the POST request having many individual fields, each for the media content:

```
"MediaContentType0" : "",
"MediaUrl0" :"",
"MediaContentType1" : "",
"MediaUrl1" :""
```

Upon detection of the media in the POST request (!=0 `NumMedia`) you should iterate over the fields to [retrieve interesting arguments](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media).

Please see below sample implementation:

```
// Build name value pairs for the incoming web hook from Twilio
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
// Type the name value pairs
string strFrom = nvc["From"];
string strNumMedia = nvc["NumMedia"];
string strBody = nvc["Body"];

// Holds the image type and link to the images
List<string> listMediaUrl = new List<string>();
List<string> listMediaType = new List<string>();
List<Stream> listImages = new List<

// Find if there was any multimedia content

if (int.Parse(strNumMedia) != 0) {
  // If there was find out the media type and the image url so we can pick them up
  for (int intCount = 0; intCount < int.Parse(strNumMedia);) {
    // Store the media type for the image even through they should be the same
    listMediaType.Add(nvc[("MediaContentType" + intCount).ToString()]);
    // Store the image there is a fair chance of getting more then one image Twilio supports 10 in a single MMS up to 5Mb
    listMediaUrl.Add(nvc[("MediaUrl" + intCount).ToString()]);
    // Update the loop counter
    intCount = intCount + 1;
  }
}
```